# How to fix "Sorry, an item is restricted in sharing." when using gapi batch requests to create a permission

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using the JavaScript [Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript) to work with the Google Drive API. I have set up a batch request to create permissions on a number of files in Google Drive. Each change is intended to add a user as a viewer/reader of the file.

I've managed to get the files shared correctly by calling the API directly for each file, however even for 4 or 5 files, it's quite slow to call the API each time. I've successfully created batch requests for other functions such as listing Google Classroom assignments and copy Google Drive files (after manually sharing them).

This will work:

```
var permissionParams = {
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "user",
  "emailAddress": emailToShareTo
};

for (f = 0; f < files.length; f++) {
  var fileID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  var permissionParams = {
    "role": "reader",
    "type": "user",
    "emailAddress": emailToShareTo
  };

  await gapi.client.drive.permissions.create(
    {
      "fileId": fileId,
      "resource": permissionParams
    });
}
```

However I'm trying to do the same as part of a batch like so:

```
function permissionRequest(fileId,params) {
  return gapi.client.request({
    'path': 'drive/v3/files/' + fileId + '/permissions?supportsAllDrives=true&sendNotificationEmail=false',
    'body': params,
    'method': 'POST'
   });
}

function doSharing() {
  var shareBatch = gapi.client.newBatch();
  var permissionParams = {
    "role": "reader",
    "type": "user",
    "emailAddress": secondaryEmail
  };

  for (f = 0; f < files.length; f++) {
    var fileId = files[f].id;
    var filePermissionRequest = permissionRequest(fileId,permissionParams)
    shareBatch.add(filePermissionRequest, {'id': fileId + '-share'});
  }

  await shareBatch.then(async function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
domain: "global"
message: "Bad Request. User message: "Sorry, an item is restricted in sharing.""
reason: "invalidSharingRequest"
```

I know that the files can be shared because I can share them through the Drive UI or using the `gapi.client.drive.permissions.create` method so I'm confident that it's not anything on the domain that's restricting the sharing. I've also tried it to/from different accounts on different domains.

I'm really struggling to understand the error. I've tried to recreate it using the API Explorer but haven't been able to achieve that.

Grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use batch. It's not what you think.

You can increase your throughput by simply sending multiple requests in parallel, and use Promise.all to know when they care complete. That will simplify your error/retry handling because you don't have to parse a batch response.

Using multiple concurrent posts, or a batch of posts, you will hit a rate limit after sending 30 or so. When this happens you will need to throttle and retry. Again, this is much easier to do if you are sending separate requests.